# If $x^n$ is ivertible in a ring show that $x$ is invertible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (non-commutative) and $x$ an emenent of $R$ so that $x^n$ is invertible for some $n\ge1$ then $x$ is invertible.

The only idea that i have is that if $y$ is the inverse of $x^n$ then $x^ny=1=yx^n\Rightarrow x(x^{n-1}y)=1=(yx^{n-1})x$ so for $x$ to be invertible it suffices to show that $x^{n-1}y=yx^{n-1}$ but i don't see how i can make progress with that.

Comment: So to be precise, your question is how to show that, given a left inverse of $x$ and a right inverse of $x$, the two must be the same even in a non-commutative ring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general $yx=1, xz=1, y(xz)=y=(yx)z=z$